# AutoLisp Autocad; "; error: no function definition: [DEFINE "

Tags: error-handling, autocad, autolisp, autocad-scripts

Hi my Dearest Friends..

I get this  message    "; error: no function definition: [DEFINE " when I run the below AutoLisp code in AutoCad, Could please somebody show me what is expecting Autocad?, what does it expect [ Define..?..  how can I do it...

This is the code..

```lisp
 defun C:DDs(       [define program] 
    (setq a (getstring "Qty? "))
    (setq b (getstring "Lot? "))

        (if (= a b)
           (progn
             (princ "HoHoH ")
           );end progn
           (progn
             (princ "Hihihii")
           );end progn
        );end if

)
```

Thanks a  lot, all the best to all of you...

I tryed to rid of the error message when i run mi autolisp app

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. You are missing an opening parenthesis before the `defun` expression:

   ```lisp
   (defun c:DDs
   ^---------------------- Here
   ```
2. `[define program]` is not valid syntax in AutoLISP - instead, the `defun` expression should be supplied with a list of arguments and/or local variables, e.g.:

   ```lisp
   (defun c:DDs ( / a b )
       ...
   )
   ```